# How can we use dense_rank() function in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am running pyspark script in which i am running sql query and creating dataframe.
In sql query there is dense_rank() function. Due to this query is taking too much of time to execute completely.

Is there any way to execute the query fast or can we handle this in pyspark level?
Is any function or method available in pyspark to replace dense_rank() from sql?

SQL:

```
SELECT  DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY SOURCE_COLUMN_VALUE) AS SYSTEM_ID,SYSTEM_TABLE_NAME,SOURCE_ID,SOURCE_NAME,SOURCE_TABLE_NAME,SOURCE_COLUMN_NAME,SRC_VALUE AS SOURCE_COLUMN_VALUE,IM_INSERT_DT FROM (SELECT ID AS SOURCE_ID,'AMPIL' AS SOURCE_NAME,UPPER(concat(coalesce(addr_line_1,''),';',coalesce(addr_line_2,''),';',coalesce(city_1,''),';',coalesce(state_1,''),';',coalesce(zip_1,''),';',coalesce(cntry_1,''))) as  SOURCE_COLUMN_VALUE,concat(coalesce(addr_line1_src,''),';',coalesce(addr_line2_src,''),';',coalesce(city_src,''),';',coalesce(state_crc,''),';',coalesce(zip_1,''),';',coalesce(cntry_1,'')) as SRC_VALUE,SOURCE_TABLE_NAME,'ADDRESS' AS SYSTEM_TABLE_NAME,SOURCE_COLUMN_NAME,date_format(current_timestamp(),'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss') as IM_INSERT_DT from (SELECT ID,regexp_replace(addr_line_1,' ','') as addr_line_1,Upper(addr_line_1) as addr_line1_src,regexp_replace(addr_line_2,' ','') as addr_line_2 ,upper(addr_line_2) as addr_line2_src,regexp_replace(UPPER(coalesce(city,meli_city_nm)),' ','') as city_1,UPPER(coalesce(city,meli_city_nm)) as city_src,regexp_replace(coalesce(meli_stt_provncd,coalesce(vw_states_code.state_cd,state)),' ','') as state_1, coalesce(meli_stt_provncd,coalesce(vw_states_code.state_cd,state)) as state_crc,case when UPPER(coalesce(vw_states_code.country_cd,country)) = 'US' then 'USA' when UPPER(coalesce(vw_states_code.country_cd,country)) = 'CANADA' then 'CA' else regexp_replace(UPPER(coalesce(vw_states_code.country_cd,country)),' ','') end as cntry_1,case when UPPER(coalesce(vw_states_code.country_cd,country)) = 'US' then regexp_extract(substr(trim(regexp_replace(zip,' ','')),0,5),'^[0-9]{5}$',0) else regexp_replace(zip,' ','') end as zip_1,SOURCE_TABLE_NAME,SOURCE_COLUMN_NAME from vw_addr_stg LEFT JOIN (select * from vw_dmn_meli_zip where MELI_LAST_LN = 'L') vw_dmn_meli  on vw_addr_stg.zip=vw_dmn_meli.meli_zip_cd_base LEFT JOIN vw_states_code on (coalesce(meli_stt_provncd,state) = vw_states_code.state_cd or vw_states_code.state_nm = vw_addr_stg.state) LEFT JOIN vw_country_codes on vw_country_codes.country_name = vw_addr_stg.country))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `pyspark`, you might use a combination of `Window` functions and `SQL` functions to get what you want. I am not SQL fluent and I haven't tested the solution but something like that might help you:

```py
import pyspark.sql.Window as psw
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf

w = psw.Window.partitionBy("SOURCE_COLUMN_VALUE")
df.withColumn("SYSTEM_ID", dense_rank().over(w))
```

You can find the doc for `dense_rank` [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=window#pyspark.sql.functions.dense_rank)

Comment: The documentation link seems to have changed:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Window.html?highlight=window#pyspark.sql.Window

Comment: and https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.dense_rank.html?highlight=dense_rank